# Is there a way to use BigQuery with Dataproc?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I've used Dataproc with data on Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) by connect to GCSQL with an IPv4 address. Is there any connection from Dataproc to BigQuery so that I can use data on BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hadoop BigQuery connector can be used from Cloud Dataproc: https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector